# Visual Studio Web API, run timed triggered commands on connected database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am building a UWP app for practice and I am attempting to connect to a database server and run commands and return data back to the application.

So far I have been successful in developing a Web Service to communicate with the DB SQL server and I am using GET methods to return results from queries.

My next goal is to be able to perform time triggered events on the SQL Database independent of whether the UWP application is running. The type of tasks would be to to update a table based of results from another database.

Is there a mechanism that would allow me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at sql jobs. You can setup a schedule pretty much as flexible as you need.

Comment: Create a Windows Service which will do timer triggered tasks. Add HTTP end point to this service and request this end point from Web API.

Comment: Where you want to trigger this event? Server or client?

Comment: I would like to trigger the event on the server